# Executing a bash script and building docker image

Tags: python, bash, docker, airflow

I have a airflow docker image which is customised with some python packages. I have a custom .whl package to build before I start all the containers and this is a one time build. This is my DockerFile and Script

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.3.3
USER root
RUN adduser airflow sudo
RUN chown -R airflow:sudo /home/airflow
RUN chmod 755 /home/airflow
USER airflow
WORKDIR /home/airflow
RUN mkdir -p /home/airflow/unifiedvoc/{config,dist,log}
RUN python3 -m venv sample_env
# RUN source sample_env/bin/activate
RUN python3 -m pip install --user pipx
RUN python3 -m pipx ensurepath --force
RUN pipx install poetry==1.2.0
COPY ./script.sh /home/airflow
RUN cd /home/airflow/
USER root
RUN chmod +x /home/airflow/script.sh
USER airflow
RUN /home/airflow/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["airflow celery worker]
```

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/airflow/xxxx
poetry build 
python3 -m pip install /home/airflow/xxxx.py3-none-any.whl
```

I am getting an error in `docker-compose up` when I use the `RUN` command to execute the `script.sh` and while giving the script to execute at `ENTRYPOINT` it gets executed on all containers but I want this to execute only on `airflow-worker` container so that I can import it in Dags. How to resolve this?